# Constructing a sequence of function

Tags: sequence-of-function

Construct a sequence of functions on [0,1] each of which is discontinuous at every point on [0,1] and which converges uniformly to a function that is continuous at every point?

Comment: Any thoughts?   Can you give a single example of such a discontinuous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } x \text{ rational} \\
    \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x \text{ irrational}
  \end{cases}
$$

Comment: You're welcome.